# Disabling (Greying out) multiple GUI Items in C++

Tags: c++, mfc

**Question:**
I am looking for an effective way to disable(grey) **mutiple** items in a MFC C++ application.  Depending on if the user is signed into a SQL Server or Oracle account, I wish to disable a section of GUI items.

**What I have tried:**
I have used the following code to disable one of my two "Create User" buttons.

```
if(checkIsSQLServer())
{
    CWnd *oraCreateUser = GetDlgItem(BTN_ORA_CREATE);
    oraCreateUser->EnableWindow(false);  //Disable Oracle "Create User" button
}
else
{
    CWnd *sqlCreateLogin = GetDlgItem(BTN_SQL_CREATE); 
    sqlCreateLogin->EnableWindow(false);  //Disable SQL Server "Create User" button.
}
```

[image]
.

This code works perfectly, however it only disables the button.  I wish to disable all items within either groupbox.

Do I need to create a `CWnd*` object for every item I wish to disable?  Is there a more effective way, such as a way to disable all items that are contained within a group box?

Comment: CodeGuru has an article about this.  Alas, the solution appears to be to write a function to do it. http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/article.php/c2145/EnablingDisabling-a-Group-of-Controls.htm

Comment: You can create an array of dialog IDs and loop through them instead of writing code for each individually. Or you could iterate through the windows starting with the first control and ending with the last in each group.

Comment: The idea of using an array of dialog IDs is excellent.  Thank you for your response @MarkRansom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this:

```
void EnableDlgItem (CWnd *dlg, int items[], BOOL bEnable)
{
  int i = 0, item ;

  while ((item = items[i++]) != 0)
  {
    CWnd *pControl = dlg->GetDlgItem(item) ;

    if (pControl != NULL)
      pControl->EnableWindow(bEnable) ;
  }
}

...
```

And in some `CYourDialog::OnSomethingFunction()`

```
static int ids[] = {IDOK, IDC_EDIT1, IDC_EDIT2, 0};
EnableDlgItem(this, ids, FALSE);
```

Comment: Great idea to include the bEnable flag as a parameter, so the method can be used for more dynamic UI affects.  Also, it is not necessary (and actually is harmful) to cast the `CWnd *` return of `GetDlgItem` to a `CButton *` since `EnableWindow` is a `CWnd` method (and you can use it for IDs that are NOT bound to `CButton`s).

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, MFC does not expose a method that allows you to enable/disable a group of controls.  You'll need to craft your own code to do that.

I was faced with the very same situation and decided to handle it by deriving my own groupbox class.  In my situation, the groupbox enable/disable functioning was tied to the state of a checkbox as seen below.

[image]

(I've redacted some information from it).

Clicking on the checkbox will toggle the enable/disable of **all** controls within the groupbox.  There's nothing stopping you from deriving your own class for the groupbox and exposing a method that can be called (rather than a checkbox) to enable/disable controls.  The advantage to this approach is that if you create the class in a generic manner, you can re-use it in other situations where a groupbox is the "parent" of other controls.